# Free CUSIP Lookup API

Tags: api

Anyone know of an API that will take a CUSIP and return a stock's symbol and vise versa?

Comment: similar question on different site (where it is on-topic): https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/52215/31831

Answer (score 7):

Fidelity has a symbol lookup tool.

For example, CUSIP `037833100` returns the ticker and company name for Apple.

http://activequote.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml?scCode=E&searchBy=C&searchFor=037833100

Answer (score 4):

I've had luck with the following query from Vanguard.

Similar to another response, CUSIP `037833100` returns the ticker and company name for Apple, as well as delayed market info.

https://investor.vanguard.com/search/?query=037833100

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://www.xignite.com/xSecurity.asmx

Answer (score 1):

S&P assigns CUSIPs and sells access to their data through various (expensive) fee models.

https://www.access.cusip.com/home.htm

Answer (score 0):

Fidelity has a nice lookup, but this one is for bonds, not stocks. I figured others may find it useful, as I stumbled across this question first.

https://fixedincome.fidelity.com/ftgw/fi/FISearchIndividualBonds